# Is there no ways to Use Query without Class Data Model in SQLite.Net? (UWP)

Tags: c#, sqlite, uwp

I'm making DB Module using SQLite.Net

however, Is there no ways to Use Query without Class Data Model in SQLite.Net??
(in UWP)

i'm using SQLite.Net-PCL v3.1.1 by Nuget.

like this, (this is a pseudo code)

```
using (SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection conn)
{
   conn.connect("filepath");
   DataReader rdr = connn.Query ("select * from customers;");

   while ( rdr.EOF() )
   {
      int iCustomerID = rdr.Rows["CustomerID"];
      string strCustomerName = rdr.Rows["CustomerName"];
      int iCurrentPoint = rdr.Rows["CurrentPoint"];
   }
}
```

without using Class Data Model.

Thank you!

Comment: Did you want to read data without ORM?

Comment: yes. without ORM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `SqliteCommand` and `sqliteconnection` to read data with `DataReader`

[Example](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2017/02/06/using-sqlite-databases-uwp-apps/)

Comment: Thank you for answering!

Comment: can you help me if possible??
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48457786/how-to-direct-shared-path-to-microsoft-data-sqlite-connection-string-uwp