# How to direct shared path to Microsoft.Data.SQLite Connection String? (UWP)

Tags: c#, sqlite, uwp

i'm making 2 UWP apps, and i want to make them share 1 DB.

i'm using Microsoft.Data.SQLite

however, is there any way to share the same DB??

```
SqliteConnection db = new SqliteConnection("Filename=data.db"));
```

> "Filename=data.db" path was c:\Users(user
>   name)\AppData\Local\Packages(App ID)\LocalState\data.db

However, I know UWP app can only access that c:\Users\ (username)\AppData\Local\Packages(App ID)\LocalState\ folder except shared app data folders.

So, can you tell me how to direct the shared app data folder to Connection String?

Comment: Can you try the [publisher shared folder](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2016/05/24/sharing-your-local-app-data/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are two ways to that:

1) Creates a button to call user action to select the common folder using a Picker to file or folder. Your application stores the access token returned by this explicit authorization and use that in future with no new user interaction.

2) Have a few ways to app get store authorization, but some that needs an enterprise Windows Store association (like Documents Library). I not sure, but for some locations, in the app validation you will be required to justify the needs before to publish your app.

More details in here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions. See the title "Accessing additional locations".

Comment: Unfortunately the folder returned from a FolderPicker can't be used to share a SQLite database

Comment: Thank you for answering!

Comment: Interesting, I did not know that. I looked at the PCL source code and noticed that the problem is the way SqLitePCL.raw accesses the files. Thanks for the info!

Comment: But user8977483, I'll give you an idea: if your 2 apps do not need to change data in real time, you can use the StorageFile result of the picker to copy the sqlite database between a default location set by the picker and the accessible folder in Windows.Storage .ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder. Example: Each app maintains the local database, but has a function that allows you to copy data to and from the common database. Because if you copy the file via picker to LocalFolder you usually have access to the copy by the sqlite driver.

Comment: Otherwise I believe you will need to use web / cloud for storage or a .net core application.

Comment: Thank you for explaining detail information! i try it.